# Node-gyp fails when running npm start on windows 10

Tags: python, node.js, npm

I installed Node.js version 12.18.1 and python v3.8.1 on windows 10, when I run npm install in a project I got this error:

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                       ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:303:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:315:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:286:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\x199377\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\react-whiteapp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\x199377\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\react-whiteapp\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v12.18.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is due to `node-sass v14.4 0` which is dependant on `node-gyp v3.8.0`, I downgraded python from v3 to v2 to fix this problem.